# Where to remember values needed for onSelect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, html-select

Old-school programmer asks how best to do something in the modern era...

I use PHP to get data from a database table like this:

```
SELECT AddrPrintName,Tategaki,DefaultStamp FROM addrprint ORDER BY ListOrder
```

I build a select with options based on AddrPrintName (names of print layouts) like this:

```
<select name="addr_print_name" size="1">
   <option value="#3L (A4 tri)">#3L (A4 tri)</option>
   <option value="#6 (A5) Rainbow Club">#6 (A5) Rainbow Club</option>
   <option value="はがき">はがき</option>
   <option value="年賀状">年賀状</option>
   <option value="角形3号 (B5) Rainbow Club">角形3号 (B5) Rainbow Club</option>
</select>
```

And I have two other form elements like this:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" value="yes" name="kanji_numbers" id="kanji_numbers">Use kanji for numbers</label>
<h4>Post office stamp:</h4>
<input type="radio" name="po_stamp" id="stamp_none" value="none">None<br />
<input type="radio" name="po_stamp" id="stamp_betsunou" value="betsunou">Standard mail<br />
<input type="radio" name="po_stamp" id="stamp_yuumail_betsunou" value="yuumail_betsunou">'Yuu-mail'<br />
<input type="radio" name="po_stamp" id="stamp_kounou" value="kounou">Standard mail w/ contract<br />
<input type="radio" name="po_stamp" id="stamp_yuumail_kounou" value="yuumail_kounou">'Yuu-mail' w/ contract
```

The Tategaki and DefaultStamp columns tell me the desired default selection status of the checkbox and radio group, so when the value of the select changes (the user chooses a different layout), I want to set the checkbox and radio group accordingly. I understand that the onChange event on the select element is the best event to use, but where would I put the other two settings? I'm an old-school coder, and 15 years ago I would have hidden the information in the option values somehow, like `value="#3L (A4 tri)|1|betsunou"` or something, but that's an ugly kluge and requires cleanup code when the form is submitted. I could define a Javascript array at the time I build the markup, but that's cumbersome, too (especially because right in the middle of an HTML select is not where the script code needs to be, so I'd have to built it in a PHP string and echo it later). I wish I could do something like this to keep everything in one place (pseudocode of daydreams, as I know there is no such event):

```
<option value="#3L (A4 tri)" onChangedToMe="document.getElementById("kanji_numbers").checked = true; document.getElementById("stamp_betsunou").checked = true;">#3L (A4 tri)</option>
<option value="#6 (A5) Rainbow Club" onChangedToMe="document.getElementById("kanji_numbers").checked = false; document.getElementById("stamp_yuumail_betsunou").checked = true;">#6 (A5) Rainbow Club</option>
```

But apparently option tags don't have any events I can grab, so it would be either `onChange="someFunction()"` on the select overall, or do it all in jQuery. But I don't know where to keep the settings. Would it be safe to put them in the option tag as fake attributes and then use them in a jQuery event handler? (e.g. `<option value="#3L (A4 tri)" kanji_numbers="1" stamp="betsunou">#3L (A4 tri)</option>`) Basically, my question is: how is this sort of thing most commonly/elegantly handled these days? It's hard to google for the answer, because I don't know the current terminology to search for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use HTML 5  `data` attributes to achieve this

```
<option value="#3L (A4 tri)" data-kanji-numbers="1" data-stamp="betsunou">#3L (A4 tri)</option>
```

Then you can read this value using [Jquery](https://api.jquery.com/data/) as

```
$('select option:selected').data("kanjiNumbers") //returns 1
$('select option:selected').data("stamp") //returns betsunou
```

Comment: Works like a charm - thanks! I didn't know about the data attributes - very helpful.